# Nest.js How to listen to all Kafka topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to create a logger service that will listen to all Kafka topics in the cluster and store them in DB. How can I tell Kafka that I would like to listen to all topics? My simple approach with wildcard @EventPattern('*') didn't work...

Any idea how can I define it in my consumer?

```
@EventPattern('*')
  async listen(
    message: KafkaMessage<Message<any>>,
  ): Promise<any> {    
    console.log(
      `KAFKA.produce: listen ${message.headers?.['x-correlation-id']} ${message.value.data}`,
    );
 }
```

Comment: [This open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3083) has some workarounds that may help you.
However, NestJs doesn't provide it out of the box.